# Searching an ArrayAdapter and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an inventory list of 100K+ items stored in an ArrayAdapter.  I use this to populate a ListView.  I use an EditText box with a TextChangedListener to jump around the inventory list based on what is typed in the EditText box. Currently, my first approach was to code the following...

```
    ListView01.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(charSeq.toString()));
```

This searches the ArrayList to give me the item position in the array and the setSelection jumps the ListView to that point in the list.  This works just fine but it only works for exact matches and does not provide quite the functionality I need.  I would like to jump around the list regardless of exact match or not.  If I start typing 'c', I want the list to jump to the first item beginning with 'c' and to keep jumping around the list as I type instead of only jumping to a position based on an exact match.

So, is their a function like "startsWith" that can be used to search the arrayAdapter or ListView to give me the position to jump to?  Is their another approach I should take?  I do not want to set up a filter since this removes items from the view.  I tried this approach already.  The filter also takes 45 seconds to filter through the inventory list after typing the first letter.  I want to freely scroll up or down through the list after I jump to a new position without any item removed from the ListView.

Comment: If this java/android (or something else) please add the relevant tags to your question.

Comment: I have tags for the question.  This is an Android app displaying a listView from an ArrayAdapter.  I'm looking for a method to fine tune how I jump around the listView on partial matches rather than exact matches.